# iOS : Getting FriendList along with respective name, id and picture using FBGraph API

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, fb-graph

You  can get `friendList` along with `respective` `name and id` using `FBGraph API`  like this:

```
  FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbgraph doGraphGet:@"/me/friends" withGetVars:nil];
```

But how to get `name, id and picture` of `all friends` using `FBGraph API`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `friendList` along with respective `name, id and picture` using `FBGraph API` like this:

```
NSDictionary *param=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"picture,name",@"fields", nil];

FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbgraph doGraphGet:@"/me/friends" withGetVars:param];
```

`Response` will be

```
data = {
   id = 100001625299089;
   name = "Name here";
   picture = {
              data = {
                      s_silhouette" = 0;
                      url = "url here";
                      };
              };
 },
    //all other friends here
 }
```

**EDIT** : You can `loaction`, `birthday`, and many `other fields` listed in [FBGraph API Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/FriendList/).

Just change `param dictionary` in above code

```
 NSDictionary *param=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"picture,name,location,birthday",@"fields", nil];
```